# Contiki compile error

Tags: contiki

I'm working with Tmote-sky nodes. I have installed instant-contiki as a virtual machine using VMware player. Now I can't compile any .c file on the nodes. I have always this error message:

```
make: msp430-gcc: Command not found
  CC        ../../core/net/rime/rimeaddr.c
make: msp430-gcc: Command not found
make: *** [obj_sky/rimeaddr.o] Error 127
```

I thought that it was because of msp430-gcc toolchain. I've installed this toolchain which normally exists with instant-contiki but I still have this problem.
Can some one help me please?

Answer (score 9):

You have to install gcc-msp430 with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-msp430
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

the problem causes with little switch. remove it you're good to go.

open this file in note pad and goto line `132`

```
contiki/cpu/msp40/Makefile.msp430
```

remove `-g` switch from the following line:

```
CFLAGSNO = -Wall -mmcu=$(CC_MCU) -g $(CFLAGSWERROR)
```

the line will be:

```
CFLAGSNO = -Wall -mmcu=$(CC_MCU) $(CFLAGSWERROR)
```

just clean up and recompile.

it should work.... :)

Comment: May be this is for contiki version older than 2.7. In 2.7 version of contiki -g is not there.